# What book specifies rules for running fast on paired cyberlegs?

Tags: damage, movement, falling, cyberpunk-2020

In Cyberpunk 2020, suppose you have a team with three members: Apple, Banana, and Canteloupe.

> Movement Allowance {MA): This is an index of how fast your character
> can run (important in combat situations). The higher your Movement
> Allowance (MA), the more distance you can cover in a turn. RUN: To
> determine how far your character can run in a single combat round
> (@3.2 seconds) in meters, multiply your MA by 3. The character can run
> three times this distance in a full 10 second turn. Write this in the
> RUN section of your Hardcopy Form. LEAP: To determine how far your
> character can leap (from a running start), divide your RUN by 4.
> Write this in the LEAP section of your Hardcopy Form.

[p.26, 2020 rulebook]

The Solo, Apple, starts with a Movement Allowance of 2.
This means he can run 6 meters in 3.2 seconds and his RUN score is 18; that is, he can run 18 meters in 10 seconds. His LEAP stat is 18/4=4.5; this means he can do a running jump of 4.5 meters.

His friends, Banana and Canteloupe, have Movement Allowances of 3 and 4. They have RUN scores of 27 and 36; thus they have LEAP stats of 6.75 and 9, respectively. Because the basic rules do not mention vertical leaping, I assume that they cannot vertically leap to any major extent.

This solo, Apple, gets paired cyberlegs.

> "Characters with paired cyberlegs can leap 6 meters straight
> up, or make a running jump of up to 8 meters."

[p. 89, 2020 rulebook]

This means that Apple effectively has a LEAP stat of 8. Assuming consistent equations, Apple's RUN score should be 32. So Apple can run faster than Banana but is still slower than Canteloupe.

As far as I can tell, even though Apple can leap vertically, he is not protected from most falling damage. (If I were GM, I would say because he can leap up 6 meters, he can also fall 6 meters without taking damage IF he lands on his feet, but would take ordinary falling damage if he failed to land on his feet. I can't find anything in the rules about that.)

As play proceeds, Apple wants to modify his legs so that he can run very fast. In the core rulebook, I cannot find any rules covering this. Some old R. Talsorian books probably have various rules. Which books have rules for running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Falling damage on its own isn't a thing, you take damage from fumbled skill rolls.**

Fall damage is a reflex, athletics thing that happens when you fail at climbing. See p50.

> Athletics. This skill is required for accurate throwing, climbing, and balancing.

p43 covers the consequences for falling on the fumble table, which range from nothing happening, to 1 point in minor damage and a stun save, to 1d6 damage and a stun save at -1. Unless you are doing an athletics roll, you don't take fall damage.

**If you want increased movement, speed, you need increased MA. There are several options.**

From Chromebook 4.

Corvette Cyberlegs (basic) offer +3 MA, +1 on movement rolls.
Corvette Cyberlegs (advan) offer +8 MA, +2 on movement rolls.

From Solo of Fortune.

Speeding Bullet Legs MA 16.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer.

Comment: Glad to help you.